# Why does attending of texfield works once this way textfield.value, the other time i have to use $("#textfield").val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following HTML:

```
<div class="form-inline">
   <span>Name:</span>
   <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name eingeben..." required/>
</div>

<div class="form-inline">
   <span>Tierart:</span>
   <input id="species" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tierart eingeben..." required/>
</div>
<div class="form-inline">
   <span>Rasse:</span>
   <input id="breed" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rasse eingeben..." required/>
</div>
<div class="form-inline">
   <span>Chip-Nummer:</span>
   <input id="chipnr" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Chip-Nummer eingeben..."/>
</div>
```

In the script-tag I put the values in a dictionary:

```
var data = {
    name: $("#name").val(),
    species: species.value,
    breed: breed.value,
    chipnr: chipnr.value
}
```

The way of attending works for the other fields, but not for the name-field, in the dictionary name is "undefined", why and how could I change this?

Comment: There is no `name` attribute used in your HTML code.

Comment: You must `select` element into variable. `#name` use jquery selector. Document method can select by `id` via `var species = document.getElementById("species")`. You may use this methods when dom structure of document is ready. If you have jquery on page, you may change `species.value` to `$("#species").val()`.

Comment: @palaѕн but why does it work for the species for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change source of values to the jquery select by id of element:

```
var data = {
    name: $("#name").val(),
    species: $("#species").val(),
    breed: $("#breed").val(),
    chipnr: $("#chipnr").val()
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this, but why does it work for species and the rest?

Comment: Yep, I make mistake... If in your javascript has values `species.value`, `breed.value`, `chipnr.value` then are setup in another javascript code on page. This may be declared basic javascript dom methods. In form on direct access you have `document.forms[0].name` as name attribute of form. Not input `name` value. `document.forms[0].species.value` works. Try use more specific keyword for input's id value.